# Html css layouts- Web Mobile suppoort

Tags: html, css

I have a page set out similar to this:

[image: my current page]

My question is about mobile support and how should I go about doing the following:

When the user resizes the window to about the size of  a smartphone screen, I want to remove the main content, which is everything below the header area/login, and keep only the header, the login form and the footer. So I have been using css media queries to do this. My problem is that my login form markup resides within the header area.

```
<div id = "header">
 <div id= "logo"><img src =""/> </div>

 +-------form markup here------+
 |<div id= "login-form">..... </div>|
 + ----------------------------+

</div>
<div id= "main-content">
  This is where I want to put the login form
</div>
```

So my question is, How should I do this?

1. should I just create another css file and link/apply that when the screen width-height is detected to be smartphone size ?
2. Should I create the markup block inside main-content, and set its css style display to none UNTIL the screen is resized to smartphone size, where a media query is set to change display attribute ?

What is the best way to accomplish this? I greatly appreciate any help and at least, some little explanation to justify that answer. Also links and other references are very welcome !

Cheers..

Comment: If the login form is inside the header, and you want to keep the header and the login form, where is the problem?

Comment: The 'problem' is that since the login form will be the main content of the page, and the header's height will drastically decrease, according to screen size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Media Queries to hide and show content based on device or device width/height.

**Here's a good Media Queries Cheat-sheet:**

http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

I wouldn't position the form as 'absolute' and put it outside the header as another poster suggested. This is super sloppy and bad practice. What's the 'absolute' form going to be positioned too? The body? Aghh. You'd need a wrapper - and that's just more code. You can do it all via CSS. Just use Media Queries to change the CSS styles for the header, show/hide elements, and reposition.

**OR**

**JQUERY** (Not the best route, but for what you want you're a limited without a redesign). I kept it simple for easy explanation. Note, I haven't tested this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var maxwidth = $(window).width(); // get device window width
    var form = $('#login-form'); // form

    if(maxwidth <= 320) { // 320 px or whatever you want
        form.clone().appendTo('#main-content'); // clone form and append to main content
        form.eq(0).hide(); // hide first form, the one in the header
    }
    else {
        form.eq(0).show(); // show initial form
        form.eq(1).remove(); // remove cloned form, if set
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes I am already using mediaqueries.Are you suggesting I create the login-form markup and then use mediaqueries to show that form? Isn;t that sort of redundant? (Having the same markup in the same page..)  And Thanks for that lovely cheat sheet, will use it in future projects for sure.

Comment: No, not suggesting that. You're in a bit of a mess. It's not easy what your trying to do, with your current structure. But you want to avoid duplicate code and absolute positioning - I would anyways. Have you explored css-frameworks such as Bootstrap or Foundation? Might make your life a little easier.

Comment: You could clone the form div via jQuery and add it to the `#main-content`. Not the best practice either, but I can give you an example.

Comment: Mike, I haven't touched css frameworks yet as I want to know css inside out before delving into frameworks. However, I will be using something of the sort very soon. Will there be a 'neat' solution for this,  if I did use a framework? Or as you said, it's a bit of a design flaw which I have to deal with. Regarding the JQuery solution, it sounds interesting. I would love to see how that works! 
Cheers!

Comment: I'm horrible at explaining things...lol. This article would do it better than I ever could. You said you want to know CSS inside out? A framework shouldn't hold you back. It might even give you the tools to learn more - or avoid some complicated CSS headaches. Though those are growing pains you should prob go through.. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/09/21/css-frameworks-css-reset-design-from-scratch/

Comment: This seems like a suitable way for doing it Mike. I understand it's not perfect, and a better markup structure would have been best, but Im grateful for this original workaround.I would not have come up with this

Comment: No prob. it's not pretty...you'll prob have to play around with the jQuery function I wrote a bit (not sure the function will kick in on page load - only when the browser is resized) - and you'll need to style with Media Queries. But it should be a good start...

Comment: Hehe, same here! Mike, you're awesome! I love some light reading before going to bed and this is just what I need. Actually, I might have to read it thoroughly tomorrow as it looks pretty good! Thnks

Comment: Yes, I will manage to work with this, surely its some good ol' jquery to the rescue. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I can see two ways you could go about accomplishing your goal:

1. Take your login-form out of the header div, put it in the main-content div and absolutely position it to make it appear inside the header when on a desktop screen, then use a media query to move it to below the header for viewing on mobile devices.
2. Use your idea of having two login-forms: one in the header, and one in the main-content area. Use media queries to change the display attribute so that the correct login-form is showing at the right time depending on the screen size. I'm not sure if duplicating the login-form is good practice, so I would try option 1 to start.

Let me know if this works out!

Comment: Both of these ideas are bad practices for sure. Duplicate code is never good. Nor is absolute positioning items to the page's body.

Comment: Yes that was what I am afraid of! Im all about best practice approach,  I will definitely try out the first option you suggested.. As for option2, I also believe redundant markup is a dirty way of doing it, especially if one is working on large projects, which do not care for extra lines of code.

Comment: Hi Mike Barwick, any suggestion from your end? I am open to all suggestions, so fire away. Greatly appreciated!